# Google Chrome jQuery ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery_hide.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("no.txt",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success")
        alert("External content loaded successfully!");
      if(statusTxt=="error")
        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});
</script>
<title>jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">Content goes here!</div>
<button id="click">Load</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So I wrote the simple code above to test out the jQuery ajax method `load()` and it doesn't work in Chrome. In fact, it returns a 404 error. Yet this code works in Firefox, IE and Safari! In case you ask I am using Chrome 26.

Any ideas?

Comment: I highly doubt that this is the issue, but you might want to start by making your DOCTYPE at least declare HTML 4

Comment: In this case if the server is returning a "404 not found" then the server was not able to find "no.txt".  Make sure your path is correct

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As a workaround I found the .get function works well.

```
$.get(_url, pars, function(data) {
     $( '#ajaxReplaceMe' ).html( data );
});
```

Where ajaxReplaceMe is the id of the (say) div element where you want the content to load.

Comment: I will have to try it out sometime.